# woocommerce subscritpions : enable early renewal

Tags: subscription, period, trial, renewal

I'm looking for a way to enable early renewal option for subscriptions that are in free trial period using the WooCommerce Subscriptions extension.

By default, it's not possible. (and I don't understand why...)

Thanks for your help,

Regards,
Johann